# Is it possible to plot points on a line graph using two separate arrays? (highcharts)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a line chart using using two separate arrays pulled from a json file to make one one.

Here is what my json file looks like

```
    {
  "time": [1240, 1250, 1300, 1310],
  "volt": [12.218, 13, 12, 14]
}
```

Here is the code I thought would work
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-elbakyan-bj7gg?file=/data.json

which uses

```
data: {
            x: jsonData.time,
            y: jsonData.volt,
        },
```

which seemed to make sense to me but isn't working

This works but the time stamps are not displaying current times or doesn't display at all
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-hamilton-kkrgt?file=/index.js

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map your data to the format required by Highcharts. In your case:

- an array of arrays with `[x, y]` values:

  ```
  series: [{
    data: jsonData2.time.map((x, index) => [x, jsonData2.volt[index]])
  }]
  ```
- or an array of objects with `{ x, y }` values:

  ```
  series: [{
    data: jsonData2.time.map((x, index) => ({ x: x, y: jsonData2.volt[index]}))
  }]
  ```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-cloud-mx9z-mx9ze?file=/index.js

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

Comment: Thank you for your help!! by any chance is there a way to enable polling for data being brought in this way through a json file or would I have to put my json file on a server then ask for it? Thanks for your help again

Comment: I am glad that I could help. As to your second question - yes, you can fetch local file in some interval, example: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-cloud-mx9z-fork-2w17p?file=/index.js